In nextjs.config redirect, how can I capture a regex group from the source and pass it to the destination?
I'm using NextJS 14.2.3 and have various redirects in my next.config.js file.
Is it possible to capture a regex group from the source and pass it to the destination?
Something like this, where the $1 and $2 are evaluated as their corresponding groups:
   // These don't work. Just a concept.
   {
     source: '/test/try-(code|saas)/do-it-(today|tomorrow)',
     destination: '/solution/try-$1/do-it-$2',
     permanent: true,
   },
   {
     source: '/:start*/youdonotwantme([0-9]?)/:end*',
     destination: '/:start*/$1/:end*',
     permanent: 'true',
   }

